# Automated backup within cloud foundry for maria db and s3

Tags: amazon-s3, mariadb, backup, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We use Cloud Foundry provided by swisscom for several of our applications. Now we ask ourselves how we can best implement automated backups within cloud foundry for db and s3. Any recommendations? Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

We use this two apps to backup mariadb's and mongodb's:

- https://github.com/seinol/db-dumper
- https://github.com/seinol/cf-backup-rotation

One app makes dumps and stores them on a s3 storage every hour and the other triggers the backup endpoint for each service according to a backup mechanism(10 backups hourly and then daily up to 20)

Recently, this official backup solution is also available, but we haven't used it yet: https://github.com/swisscom/backman